# How to get params ID to get single resource from backend using Typescript + createAsyncThunk?

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to get a single resource (one to-do) from my backend. I'm trying to setup my store in my frontend and having trouble finding the req.params.id like I would in regular Javascript + Redux thunks. I looked at some docs at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk and attempted to do the same from todoSlice file. It's giving me the following error: "Argument of type '(todoId: string, thunkApi: GetThunkAPI<{}>) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Todo, void, {}>'.
Types of parameters 'todoId' and 'arg' are incompatible.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'." I'm not sure how to get the id from parameters using Typescript and would appreciate any help. I attached my current file set up below:

left: my client side thunk. right: my backend server controller.
[image: front & backend setup]

My todoSlice code:

```
interface TodoState {
  todos: Todo[] | null;
  isFetching: boolean;
  singleTodo: Todo | null;
  errors: any;
}

export const getOneTodo = createAsyncThunk<Todo>(
  'TODO/FETCHONE',
  async(data, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/api/todos/`);
      thunkApi.dispatch(getOneTodo());
      return res.data;
    } catch(e) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(e)
    }
  }
);
```

And this is my todo router controller:

```
// get one to-do
export const getTodo = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const task = await Todo.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(task);
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(500).json({ err: e });
  }
};
```

Comment: Post code as text with correct format instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed some old code and found I con do the following:

```
export const getOneTodo = (todoId: string) => createAsyncThunk<Todo>(
  'TODO/FETCHONE',
  async(_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/api/todos/${todoId}`);
      thunkApi.dispatch(getOneTodo(todoId));
      return res.data;
    } catch(e) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(e)
    }
  }
);
```